# How to use newrelic custom metrics with azure web job?

Tags: c#, azure, newrelic, azure-webjobs

I have a web job using c# that I would like to add some custom metrics like this

```
NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.IncrementCounter("IncrementCounter");
```

From what I can tell though I need the non IIS agent but I can't find any information on implementing this with a web job.

Does anyone know of a way to set this up?

Comment: Are you using WebJob's SDK, or just a plain console app?

Comment: While I am not using the SDK I am using the NuGet packages.  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core

Comment: Have you looked at New Relics [docs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/instrumentation/instrumenting-non-iis-apps)? Their article is pretty helpful. You can use app.config to enable the agent.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, [here is the article that explains things on how to get New Relic working with a Webjob.](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-azure-webjobs)

In summary ...

For code you have to install a nuget package: NewRelic.Agent.Api and write some new relic API calling  code... eg log time taken for some custom event:

```
public void LogTimeTaken(string taskType, string eventType, long duration)
{
    var metric = string.Format("Custom/{0}_{1}", taskType, eventType);
    NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.RecordResponseTimeMetric(metric, duration);
}
```

Configure the New Relic app settings in the App.config of the webjob:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="NewRelic.AppName" value="[replace_with_the_name_you_want_reported_to_new_relic]" />
    <add key="NewRelic.AgentEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="NewRelic.LicenseKey" value="[replace_with_your_key]" />
  </appSettings>
```

In the Kudu Portal for the Web App ... AKA SCM ... Add the "New Relic" Site Extension

Once you have your webjob deployed and running you should be able to create a dashboard from your New Relic account (Tools menu, create custom dashboard).
Use the metric: Custom/* to pick up all values ... choose calls per minute to get a count of the no of runs or average value to get the duration (assuming you used the code above)